# VBA UDF for list of MM.YYYY (months) between two dates

Tags: vba, function

I am trying to list the dates between two given months: a) 1/1/2021; b) 6/1/2021 in format: 
`01.2021; 02.2021; 03.2021; 04.2021; 05.2021; 06.2021` 
I was able to find and use this UDF:

```
Function MONTHRANGE(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, _
                                Optional Delim As String = "; ", _
                                Optional dFormat As String = "MM.YYYY") As String
                                
MONTHRANGE = Join(Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(TEXT(ROW(" & CLng(startDate) & ":" & CLng(endDate) & ")," & Chr(34) & dFormat & Chr(34) & "))"), Delim)
End Function
```

The output of this is repeated dates (for each day of the month) in the format I want - how can I return just the unique values (one - per month)?

Comment: quick comment, while dealing with dates, it is better to cast them to [double](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/dates-times/index.htm). When you parse them to excel interface, get them back to dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following gets the job done:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
   Debug.Print GetMonths(CDate("1/1/2021"), CDate("6/1/2021"))
End Sub

Private Function GetMonths(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As String
   Do While StartDate <= EndDate
      GetMonths = GetMonths & Format(Month(StartDate), "00") & "." & Year(StartDate) & "; "
      StartDate = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)
   Loop
   
   GetMonths = Left(GetMonths, Len(GetMonths) - 2)
End Function
```